# New shower valve, more water, slow drain

Tags: shower, drain, valve

I have replaced the shower valve and shower head (restrictor um fell out) and as a result the tub fills up with water as the shower progresses.   So remember as a kid, the water math problem of adding 2 gallons per minute and draining 1 per minute, the tub will fill up.

Any options for increasing the tub drain flows?   I have cleaned the drain and snaked the overflow pipe both of which did not seem to be clogged but did it anyways.

The drain shoe is older and a 45 degree angle so seems like this would inhibit so one thought was to change this out for a larger or different shoe or vertical drain and p-trap.   Need to see how the overflow will tie in.

Or really just add the restrictor back in to balance the shower flow and drain flow volumes.

Sort of like the water pressure, not going to lie.

Comment: Pipe for shower is maybe 1/2 or 3/4 inch.  Pipe for drain at least 1 1/2 to 2 inch.  You have a clog in the drain pipe.

Comment: Definitely 1/2" supply as new copper was installed.  The bathroom shares the same drain stack (and common wall) with the master so 3' of pipe of which I have snaked.   Will try again with different pipe cleaner.   Thanks